# Change Ruby TK menu entry state while a variable is changing too?

Tags: ruby, windows-10, tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

Let's assume i have this menu:

```
menubar = TkMenu.new(win)
win['menu'] = menubar

edit = TkMenu.new(menubar)

menubar.add :cascade, :menu => edit, :label => 'Edit'

edit.add(:command, :label => 'Delete')
```

And i want to change the "edit" entry state when a variable is changing too.

I tried this,

```
def update_menu(edit)
  Thread.new {
   loop {

     if $variable == nil
      edit.entryconfigure 'Delete', :state => "disabled"
     else
      edit.entryconfigure 'Delete', :state => "normal"
     end

     sleep 0.1

   }
  }
end
```

And it actually works but the tk menu will flash for every tick of the loop.
I'm messing up something or is there a better way for loops in TK? It seems like a bug...

I'm on Windows 10 and this is my ruby version:
`ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]`

Comment: I believe that Tk doesn't do double-buffering of menus…

Comment: @DonalFellows, im not so much good with coding yet, so i don't know why that was happening. I found a workaround, and i will post it rn answering my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to avoid those flashes on menus.

I used `while` loops doing nothing to "pause" the thread, then when their condition become true, they will end so the `edit.entryconfigure` code will execute only once, changing the menu entry state. All this closed in a loop.

This the updated code:

```
def update_menu(edit)
 Thread.new {
  loop {

   while $variable == nil; sleep 0.1; end
   edit.entryconfigure 'Delete', :state => "normal"

   while $variable != nil; sleep 0.1; end
   edit.entryconfigure 'Delete', :state => "disabled"

   sleep 0.1
  }
 }
end
```

Now the menus looks good and no flashes there.